React fragment displays embedded link element as [object Object]
I'm having an issue getting a React fragment to display properly. I have some text with an embedded link element, but it displays the link element as [object Object] like this:
You must first verify your email address before logging in. Would you like to [object Object] the email confirmation link?

Here is the abbreviated relevant code:
export default function MyComponent() {

    let loginError: JSX.Element = <>{`You must first verify your email address before logging in. Would you like to ${<Link to="../account/resend-email-confirmation" className="alert-link">resend</Link>} the email confirmation link?`}</>;

    return (
        <div>
            {loginError}
        </div>
    )
}

How can I get the link to display properly?

the reason it's not working is because you are trying to embed a React component inside a template string and then JS is converting that component to a string within the template string.
In your case, I don't think you even need to use a template string. something like this should be enough?
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
const loginError = (<>text <Link>link text</Link>text</>);
  return (
   <span>
      {loginError}
    </span>
  );
}

const Link = ({ children }) => (
  <span>
    {children}
  </span>
);


            <>
          You must first verify your email address before logging in. Would
          you like to
          <Link
            to="../account/resend-email-confirmation"
            className="alert-link"
          >
            resend
          </Link>
          the email confirmation link?`
        </>

Try this instead

That is what I initially had, but it adds quotation marks around the text before and after the link element which messes up the formatting

    <span>       You must first verify your email address before logging in. Would you like       to       <Link to="../account/resend-email-confirmation" className="alert-link">         resend       </Link>       the email confirmation link?
 I'm just using it right now in my React app, and there is nothing wrong with it. maybe something with your styling try removing the alert-link class. and dont use this: {...`}

Wrapping the contents with  instead of <></> worked for me. Thanks.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
